# zoomToExtend openlayes 2.13.1 issue

Tags: openlayers-2

my layers are in wgs84 and I need to zoomToExtend to  specific Bound's  but it seems I can not make it....
The  code seems ok but nothing happens.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            fallThrough:false,
            units: "m", 
            projection: googleMercator,
            displayProjection: wgs84
       });
.
.
.
.       
        var minLat = 38.79;
        var minLng = 24.09;
        var maxLat = 42.08;
        var maxLng = 25.61;

        map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(minLng,minLat,maxLng,maxLat).transform(wgs84, googleMercator));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved my issue by the following code:

```
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(28.1231635,40.357895).transform(wgs84,googleMercator), 5);
```

Since I gave the coordinates to wgs84, i needed to transform them to googleMercator.